# Combine multiple .csv files into a .log file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have 3 csv files (and none, all, or some might be blank). They all have different headers, so I want the headers and values listed in a .log. For the 3 file contents, I want it seperated by using new lines. Anyone know the syntax for this?

Comment: What have you tried as there are many ways to do this - I would suggest starting with [using Import-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx) and then either export-csv or out-file (both are linked in that same article)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the contents of your three CSVs to variables and then add them to the log file with a line break in between.  Play around with ways to do this.  Like the comment on your post, there are lots of ways to do this. Another keyword/parameter would be '-Append'

```
$content1 = get-content csv1.csv
$content2 = get-content csv2.csv
$content3 = get-content csv3.csv
Add-Content -Value $content1 -path yourtestlog.log
Add-Content -Value `n -path yourtestlog.log
Add-Content -Value $content2 -path yourtestlog.log
Add-Content -Value `n -path yourtestlog.log
Add-Content -Value $content3 -path yourtestlog.log
```

Comment: Thanks this is much cleaner than what I have.